# If I use Cypress and appium I would need 2 automation frameworks instead of 1 framework with webdriver/appium.Is 1 framework more advisable?

Tags: automation, frameworks, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

We have 2 types of users.

One that lead and support teams which has a web app. The other users are the people on those teams which has a web app along with a mobile app (android & ios)

I would like to use the Cypress automation framework for the web apps and appium for the mobile apps.  However this would need 2 different frameworks for running the automation.  If I choose to use webdriver and appium I will only need 1 framework to run both.

1. Is it better in the short or long term to go with only 1 framework (webdriver / appium)?  If yes, why?
2. Would this lead to challenges for automators to switch teams if they wish to?
3. Or is it not very significant and I can go with 2 frameworks so I can use Cypress?

Answer (score 0):

Somethings I would consider:

1. Is anything shared between the test setups for web & mobile?

   - If you are able to share (test) code it's a plus to use the same framework.
2. Are your Appium tests also in Javascript?

   - If all tests are in Javascript, there will be less friction to move between them, but if they are different, it's a plus to use the same framework/language
3. Cypress has zero support for native mobile apps

   - However, in my opinion, it is the best option for testing web sites/apps
4. How skilled is your team in Appium? Javascript?

   - If you have an Appium knowledgeable team, go with that. If your team is even moderately skilled with Javascript, cypress definitely deserves a trial.

My recommendation would be to try doing both for one or two features. See how it feels, see what overlap there is and find out if context switching is problematic or not.

Comment: From 1: a) When you say share test code, do you mean, the same tests running against both mobile and web? b) If yes, and there is no shared tests then there would be no reason to use the same framework?  Is there any benefit in this case?

Comment: Sorry, no I do not mean sharing tests specifically, because that's likely not possible with Cypress + native mobile app. I was thinking if there were utilities or even cucumber definitions, that could be shared and reduce duplication. Maybe a config file with some string definitions that you are looking for in your tests.. something like that.